# Ngram in R: calculating word frequency and sum of values

Tags: r

I would like to perform the following calculations:

**Input:**

```
Column_A                    Column_B
Word_A                      10
Word_A Word_B               20
Word_B Word_A               30
Word_A Word_B Word_C        40
```

**Output:**

```
Column_A1                   Column_B1
Word_A                      100 = 10+20+30+40
Word_B                      90  = 20+30+40
Word_C                      40  = 40
Word_A Word_B               90  = 20+30+40
Word_A Word_C               40  = 40
Word_B Word_C               40  = 40
Word_A Word_B Word_C        40  = 40
```

The order of the words in the output does not matter, so Word_A Word_B = 90 = Word_B Word_A.  Using RWeka and tm libraries I was able to extract unigrams (just one word), bit I will need to have n-gram where n=1,2,3 and calculate column_B1

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tokenizers)

df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(ngram = list(c(tokenize_ngrams(Column_A, lowercase = FALSE, n = 3, n_min = 1), 
                              tokenize_skip_ngrams(Column_A, lowercase = FALSE, n = 2), 
                          recursive = TRUE)), 
           ngram = list(unique(map_chr(strsplit(ngram, ' '), 
                                       ~paste(sort(.x), collapse = ' '))))) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    count(ngram, wt = Column_B)

## # A tibble: 7 × 2
##                  ngram     n
##                  <chr> <int>
## 1               Word_A   100
## 2        Word_A Word_B    90
## 3 Word_A Word_B Word_C    40
## 4        Word_A Word_C    40
## 5               Word_B    90
## 6        Word_B Word_C    40
## 7               Word_C    40
```

Note this is currently only robust through strings of three words. For longer strings you would have to figure out how far you want skip ngrams to go, or take a different approach altogether.